# Regex for checking some special characters

Tags: regex, c#-2.0

I need a regex to check if the input contain following characters

```
\/:*?:"<>|
```

The input can allow all the keyboard keys except  the above mentioned.

Comment: Is it intentionally the same set of valid/invalid characters as for a filename?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negated character class `[^ ]` here.

```
^[^\\/*?:"<>|]*$
```

Regular expression:

```
^                  # the beginning of the string
 [^/*?:\"<>|]*     # any character except: '\', '/', '*', '?', ':', '"', '<', '>', '|' (0 or more times)
$                  # before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

Comment: black slash is an escape sequence. So need to put twice...o expected expression is ^[^/*?:\\"<>|]*$.

Comment: I had to edit your question to be able to see the backslash was part of the characters.